# How to determine if Excel file is opened?

Tags: if-statement, autoit

My AutoIt script opens an Excel file and moves it to desktop, but I found a problem if that Excel file  was already open, so for that I need to add in my code a condition to pass if Excel file was opened.

My code :

```
#include<excel.au3>

Func _WinWaitActivate($title,$text,$timeout=0)

    WinWait($title,$text,$timeout)
    If Not WinActive($title,$text) Then WinActivate($title,$text)
    WinWaitActive($title,$text,$timeout)

EndFunc

Func _Au3RecordSetup()

    Opt('WinWaitDelay',100)
    Opt('WinDetectHiddenText',1)
    Opt('MouseCoordMode',0)
    Local $aResult = DllCall('User32.dll', 'int', 'GetKeyboardLayoutNameW', 'wstr', '')

    If $aResult[1] <> '0000040C' Then
        MsgBox(64, 'Warning', 'Recording has been done under a different Keyboard layout' & @CRLF & '(0000040C->' & $aResult[1] & ')')
    EndIf

EndFunc

HotKeySet("{F2}", "COMP")

Func COMP()
    local $var = "C:\Users\Relkassah\Desktop\changment  data.xlsx"
    local $oExcel_1 = _Excel_Open()

    _Excel_BookOpen($oExcel_1,$var)
    Sleep(300)
    _WinWaitActivate("changment  data - Excel","")
    Send("{ALTDOWN}{SPACE}m{ALTUP}")
    MouseClick("left")
    MouseDown("left")
    MouseMove(150,444)
    MouseUp("left")
    Send("{ALTDOWN}{SPACE}{ALTUP}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{DOWN}{ENTER}")

EndFunc

While 1
    Sleep(1)
WEnd
```

Comment: `_Excel_Open` `Sets @extended to: 0 - Excel was already running
///    1 - Excel was not running or $bForceNew was set to True. A new Excel instance has been created`

Answer (score 0):

Check out this function it may help you : https://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/docs/functions/WinExists.htm
you have to add if statement inside the while loop, Example :

```
    While 1
   
   If WinExists($yourwindow) Then
      ;do whatever you want here..
      EndIf
   
    Sleep(1)
WEnd
```

this function will return true or false value and while the excel is opened it will keep sending true.